# Why the 3D heat equation is $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\alpha\nabla^2u$

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity

Why the 3D heat equation is $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\alpha\nabla^2u=\alpha\left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z^2}\right)?$$

Where $u(x,y,z,t)$ is the distribution function of temperature in the position $(x,y,z)$ at time $t$.

I'm reading about the 3D heat equation but many sources assume this equation

Comment: $a$ is just the square root of the thermal diffusivity constant.

Comment: What is insufficient about the Wikipedia article on the heat equation? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation

Comment: Looking around on the internet one can find both forms, but a simple constant (without the square) seems more common. One could argue which version is "more correct" based on dimensional analysis.

Comment: what puzzles you in this equation exactly ?

Comment: It comes from the combination of the Fourier law and the first principle of thermodynamics. As @NeuroFuzzy pointed out, read the wikipedia article.

Answer (score 1):

This equation describes 3D transient heat conduction in a material, where $\alpha$ is the thermal diffusivity.  The thermal diffusivity is related to the thermal conductivity, the heat capacity, and the density by $\alpha=\frac{k}{\rho C}$.  The equation is derived by performing a differential heat balance on an infinitesimal volume of the material.  It can also be derived using an overall heat balance and the divergence theorem.  This form of the equation assumes that the thermal conductivity is independent of both spatial location and temperature u;  and it assumes that the density is likewise independent of temperature.  If you want to see a detailed derivation of the equation, see Transport Phenomena by Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/374625/on-ricci-flow-and-nonlinear-relativistic-heat-equation - the Ricci flow is the heat diffusion equation for a Riemann manifold.